# How to use SOAP service with xml in Rails (EU VAT number check)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, soap

I'd like to add a method in my Rails application that checks the validity of a VAT number using the EU's VIES system: http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/technicalInformation.html

I'm already pretty new to programming in Rails and the instructions here use `xml`. So I have trouble figuring this out. How should I include the code mentioned on the mentioned website in my Rails application?

In other words, what should the `validate_vat(country, vatnumber)` method below look like and how to process the response received from the SOAP service?

```
def vatsubmission
  @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
  @organization.update_attributes(vat_params)

  @organization.validate_vat(@organization.country, @organization.vatnumber) if (@organization.vatnumber? && @organization.vatnumber?)

  # Process response
  if valid == false
    @organization.update_attributes(valid_vat: false)
    flash.now[:danger] = "False VAT number"
    render ...
  elsif valid == true
    @organization.update_attributes(valid_vat: true)
    flash.now[:success] = "VAT number validated"
    render ...
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "VAT number could not be validated"
    render  ...
  end
end

def validate_vat(country, vatnumber)
  ??
end
```

---

**Update:** I've added `gem 'savon', '2.11.1'` to my gemfile. In my controller I have:

```
def update
  @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
  if @organization.check_valid == true
    @organization.update_attributes(validnr: true)
  else
    @organization.update_attributes(validnr: false)
  end
end
```

And I have added the following model method:

```
  require 'savon'

  def check_valid
    debugger
    if ["DK", "CY", "etc"].include? self.country
      client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl')
      resp = client.call :check_vat do
        message country_code: self.country, vat_number: self.vatnr
      end
      data = resp.to_hash[:check_vat_response]
      data[:valid]
    end
  end
```

**Error:** The line `message country_code: self.country, vat_number: self.vatnr` fails with the error message: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`. I checked with the `debugger` and `self.country` as well as `self.varnr` do have values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to follow this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/290-soap-with-savon?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For working with SOAP from Ruby I used excelent [Savon](http://savonrb.com/) gem.

With [Savon v2](http://savonrb.com/version2/), working code looks like this:

```
require 'savon'

client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl')
resp = client.call :check_vat do
  message country_code: 'AT', vat_number: '123'
end
data = resp.to_hash[:check_vat_response]
data[:valid] #=> false :)
```

**Note** Savon v3 is still in preparation.

Comment: Thanks @dimakura. I'm trying to implement as you suggested but am getting an error message. I'll add it to my original post.

Comment: @Marty did you test it locally first? You can invoke it from irb.

Comment: I tested it on the development server, irb is new to me. What should I do within irb to test it? If in the terminal I choose: `irb` then `client = Savon.client('http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl')`. This produces an error: `NameError: uninitialized constant Savon` which I think has to do that I need to `require` savon somewhere?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed `Savon.client(wsdl: '...')`. It should be working now. See update above

Comment: I updated the OP with the latest error message. The line `message country_code: self.country, vat_number: self.vatnr` fails with the error message: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`.

Comment: Found the solution. I had to change the line to: `resp = client.call(:check_vat, message: {country_code: self.country, vat_number: self.vat_number})`. Then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I've just started using the [ValVat gem](https://github.com/yolk/valvat) for this and it workd beautifully so far!