# How to write model test for SOAP request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, soap

I've written a model method that checks the validity of a VAT number using the EU's VIES system ([How to use SOAP service with xml in Rails (EU VAT number check)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32636633)). This works in development.

Now I'm trying to write a `model test` to see if the model method is able to get a response from that system:

```
test "test check_valid" do
  @organization.number = "TESTVATNUMBER"    # In def setup, @organization receives all the other relevant variables
  @organization.save
  @organization.check_vat # Calls upon the model method
  assert ???              # How to test that the previous line/method has indeed returned the value 'false' to the controller?
end
```

How to complete this test? That is, how to test that `check_vat` worked correctly and returned the value 'false' to the controller method?

These attempts below produced the error `undefined method 'assert_response' for #<OrganizationTest:0x00000007686918>`:

```
@organization.check_validity_vat_nr
assert_response :success

assert_response 'false' do
  @organization.check_validity_vat_nr
end
```

Comment: Is the method used as a validation on the model, or is it merely called from other parts of the code?

Comment: The model method is called from the controller method: `@organization.check_vat`. The method then returns the value `true` or `false` to the controller method. The controller method processes the returned value, meaning that if some other conditions are also met, it sets a variable for the organization to `true` and otherwise `false`. But here in the model test, I only want to test whether the model method indeed returns the value I'd expect it to.